# Windows Explorer - icons Large or Extra Large View - Is it possible to define a minimum distance in pixels between icons?

Tags: windows-explorer, icons, pixels

Windows Explorer - icons Large or Extra Large View - Is it possible to define a minimum distance in pixels between icons?

It would be easier to hit empty space between icons with mouse-click to open right-click menu
avoiding unintended hit of icon itself with right-click

If you don't have preview pane,
By default this distance fixed around 3 pixels.
In this case how to set distance to 10 or more pixels?

If you have preview pane,
By default this distance starting from one pixel.
As you drag the border of the preview pane with mouse
distance growing to certain limit.
In this case how to set a range of distance for example starting from 10 to 20 or more pixels?

Answer (score 0):

Negative answer, unfortunately : Such an option doesn't exist.

Explorer has the
[IconSpacing](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/how-to-change-desktop-icon-spacing-in-windows-10.html)
option for when displaying the desktop, but this only applies to the
desktop and is ignored when displaying a files/folders icons.

To be sure of right-click in an empty space, one sometimes needs
to scroll to the end of the list, to click on unused space.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Maybe this IconSpacing registry entry could be made in another area in Registry Database and that would regulate distance of icons when displaying a files/folders icons? Where would it be in Registry Database?

Comment: `IconSpacing` is only consulted when in this one place in the registry.